# Ошибка 404 при попытке отправить форму регистрации

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, регистрация

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при попытке отправить форму на базу данных страница выдаёт ошибку 404, проверял все пути и названия файлов несколько раз но так и не нашёл несоответствий, может это я немного слепой или просто проблема в другом? Помогите :(

Для работы с базами данных использовал RedBeanPHP, пути выглядят так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для обращения к библиотеке rb.php использовал другой файл, а именно db.php, код которого выглядит так:

```
    <?php
require "libs/rb.php";
R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=englishtester',
       'root', '' );
session_start();
?>
```

Код самой страницы регистрации:

```
    <?php require "db.php";?>

<?php
  $data = $_POST;
  if ( isset($_POST['do_registration']) ) 
  {

    $errors = array();
    if ( trim($data['emailGet']) == '' ) 
    {
      $errors[] = 'Введите почту';
    }

    if ( ($data['passwordGet']) == '' ) 
    {
      $errors[] = 'Введите пароль';
    }

    if ( ($data['passwordRepeatGet']) != ($data['passwordGet']) ) 
    {
      $errors[] = 'Пароли не совпадают';
    }

    if ( ($data['phoneNumberGet']) == '' ) 
    {
      $errors[] = 'Введите ваш номер телефона';
    }

    if ( empty($errors) ) 
    {
      $user = R::dispense('users');
      $user->email = $data['email'];
      $user->password = $data['password'];
      $user->phoneNumber = $data['phoneNumber'];
      R::store($user);
    } 

    else 
    {
      echo '<div style="color: red">'.array_shift($errors).'</div><hr>';
    }

  }
?>

<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></link>
<head>
<body>

<div id="registrationTable">

<form action='/registration.php' method='POST'>

<input autocomplete='off' placeholder="Эл. почта" type='email' style='font-size: 20px' id='loginInput' name="emailGet">

<input type='password' placeholder='Пароль' style='font-size: 20px' id='passwordInput' name="passwordGet">

<input type='password' placeholder='Пароль' style='font-size: 20px' id='passwordRepeat' name="passwordRepeatGet">

<input id='phoneNumberInput' placeholder = 'Тел. номер' name="phoneNumberGet">

<button id='button1' type="submit" name="do_registration">
Далее
</button>
<br>

<form action='/registration.php' method='POST'>

</div>
```

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. У формы нет закрывающего тега `</form>`
2. Попробуйте убрать action, т.к. форма сама уже находится в registration.php, если я правильно понял.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, только начал углубляться в эту тему и порой не замечаю таких глупых ошибок как не закрытый тэг, вы сэкономили кучу моего времени :)